# XenForo Avatar upload fails, $image == false - PHP7

Tags: php, php-7, xenforo

I'm stumped on a XenForo 1.5.7 / php7 issue. I've read that [tempnam() was changed as of php7](https://xenforo.com/community/threads/tempnam-warnings-with-php-7-1.124064/) (based on temp dir permissions), but I've chmod'd the directory as that link states, still to no avail.

I printed out `$newTempFile` which returns `/var/www/forum/internal_data/temp/xfJ9FLyG` (looks correct). It's the next line, the `$image` variable, that does not get set, and then throws the error in the `if()` below.

```
$newTempFile = tempnam(XenForo_Helper_File::getTempDir(), 'xf');
$image = XenForo_Image_Abstract::createFromFile($fileName, $imageType);
if (!$image)
{
    throw new XenForo_Exception(new XenForo_Phrase('image_could_be_processed_try_another_contact_owner'), true);
}
```

Here is the code for `createFromFile()` in `Image\Abstract.php`:

```
/**
 * Creates an image from an existing file.
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param integer $inputType IMAGETYPE_XYZ constant representing image type
 *
 * @return XenForo_Image_Abstract|false
 */
public static function createFromFileDirect($fileName, $inputType)
{
    throw new XenForo_Exception('Must be overridden');
}

...

public static function createFromFile($fileName, $inputType)
{
    $class = self::_getDefaultClassName();
    return call_user_func(array($class, 'createFromFileDirect'), $fileName, $inputType);
}
```

Because it looks like `createFromFileDirect()` is called from `createFromFile()`, my thought was that a "Must be overriden" error would be thrown, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Any ideas?